# Writing JSON data to file in python

Tags: python, json, writefile

I'm not quite sure on how you write a `JSON` so can you please help me, i'm trying to make this with `JSON` in `python`. Here's the pseudo-code

```
binary_students = json(students)

write_to_the_file_system(binary_students)
```

I'm not quite understanding it, can someone help me please.

Comment: [RTFD](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *dictionary* for storing Json data like this:

```
>>> dict = {'Student1':'x1','Student2':'x2'}
```

and then use the `json`library

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(dict,outfile)
```

Comment: Don't use the names of builtins for variables - it masks them and could lead to problems down the road.

Comment: @user2314737 just try dict = 1, then d = dict(foo=bar) and see what happens